# What is the correct way to make validations in JS, using the IF control structure

Tags: javascript, controls, conditional-statements

I want to know which control structure to handle validations is better

I tried with if else if, and if -> return... if -> return

Which is better and more understandable?

```
if(user.name == null) {
  errorMessage ('insert name')
} else if (user.age == null) {
  errorMessage('Insert age')
} else {
  insertUser(user)
}
```

OR

```
if(user.name == null) {
  errorMessage ('insert name')
  return
}

if (user.age == null) {
  errorMessage('Insert age')
  return
} 

insertUser(user)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not equivalent, so it's not a matter of which one is better style.

What will happen if `name` is `null` and `age` is also `null` if you use the first code block? Answer: you will only set the name, and the age will remain `null`.

So you should use the second block.

Also, instead of the check `if (a == null)` you should generally consider using something like `if (!a)`. This handles not only `null` values but also a few more falsy values (e.g. `undefined`, `''`, etc.).

Comment: If `name` is `null` and `age` is also `null`, they will both do the same.  I personally like the second version, especially if you wanted to concatenate your errors instead of showing just the first encountered.  But as the OP has written it above they will do the same.

Comment: @Keith How will they do the same?! One is `if-else if-else`, the other one is two sequential IFs.

Comment: Oh I didn't notice the `return` statements there. Sorry. Yes, they will do the same.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of performance, they are the same.

Regarding code readability, I prefer the later.

For maintenance, the later, as you may want later a list of all errors and it will be easier to implement.

How about:

```
try {
    check(user.name, 'insert name');
    check(user.age, 'insert age');
    ...
    insertUser(user);
} catch(e) {
    // handle e
}

const check = (value, message) => {
   if (!value) {
       throw `${message}`;
   }
};
```

Comment: They are the same in terms of execution, so not sure why this one got down-voted.  The accepted answer is wrong saying -> `These are not equivalent`

Comment: well they have different flow, but I meant performance is the same

Comment: Yes, I'm agreeing with you.  I think yours should have been the accepted answer, and you certainly didn't deserve the down-vote.

Answer (score 2):

The better way would be to collect all the errors first. Then check if you have any errors and finally insert a user if no errors are found.

```
const errors = ['name', 'age'].forEach( field => {
 if(user[field] === null) {
  return `${field} is required`
 }
})

if (errors.length === 0) {
 insertUser(user)
} else {
 showErrors(errors)
}
```